# GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME) unexpectedly changes count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm storing the session ID, IP address and timestamp of individual website visits, and all associated pageviews, in a database. It contains more data, but the data relevant here is extracted with this query:

```
SELECT 
Pageviews.id, Visitors.time, Visitors.session, Visitors.ip
FROM Visitors
INNER JOIN Pageviews
    ON Visitors.session=Pageviews.session
ORDER BY Visitors.time ASC
```

Which results in something like this:

```
id      time        session                     ip

1048    1371473496  nhie5sh2tiufs2ufupcremc6c2  x88.xxx.xxx.xxx
1050    1371474103  8hfphqvq5ri6muc84oidp7q195  x6x.xxx.xxx.xxx
1062    1371474956  hhgssr4v26pjbilkg8d81olqj7  xxx.x3x.xxx.xxx
1066    1371476339  ic8iqd0a4mpoelni15n4tq3404  x1x.xxx.xxx.xxx
1067    1371476629  ockivrm61upk7ss5ni4n8muv23  x2x.xxx.xxx.xxx
1070    1371477856  5tdj9rrd1qsvafovufnkgh8r26  xxx.xxx.x7x.xxx
1068    1371477856  5tdj9rrd1qsvafovufnkgh8r26  xxx.xxx.xxx.x2x
1069    1371478229  5e82v29nuf2k46ir13i21msps5  xxx.x5x.xxx.x8x
```

To get the total number of visitors (distinct IPs), visits (distinct sessions) and pageviews (distinct pageview IDs), I query the database as follows:

```
SELECT 
 count(distinct(Visitors.ip)) as 'Visitors',
 count(distinct(Visitors.session)) as 'Visits',
 count(Pageviews.id) as 'Pageviews'
FROM Visitors
INNER JOIN Pageviews
 ON Visitors.session=Pageviews.session
```

Which returns something like the below:

```
Visitors   Visits    Pageviews

211        244       412
```

However, I would like to use the stored timestamp to group those totals by year, month and day. To get that data, I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
 DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(Visitors.time)) as 'Day',
 MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(Visitors.time)) as 'Month',
 YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(Visitors.time)) as 'Year',
 count(distinct(Visitors.ip)) as 'Visitors',
 count(distinct(Visitors.session)) as 'Visits',
 count(Pageviews.id) as 'Pageviews'
FROM Visitors
INNER JOIN Pageviews
 ON Visitors.session=Pageviews.session
GROUP BY Year, Month, Day
ORDER BY Year, Month, Day DESC
```

This works fairly well, in that the dates, pageviews and visits are correct:

```
Day Month   Year    Visitors    Visits  Pageviews

20  6       2013    40          43      59
19  6       2013    80          90      112
18  6       2013    62          66      173
17  6       2013    43          45      68
```

As you can see, the pageviews here add up to the above 412, and the visits to the above 244. What's been keeping me up at night, however, is that the visitors count does not add up to 211, as it should, but instead to 225. I cannot figure out why this is happening only to the visitors count.

Sorry for the lengthy question. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a side note: `distinct` is **not** a function. Writing `distinct(foo)` is the same as `distinct foo`. The paranthesesis are totally useless and often suggest (especially when used with multiple columns) that the behaviour of `distinct` is misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're counting DISTINCT IP's, when you GROUP BY month each grouping (month) gets a count of DISTINCT IP's, ie, people can be counted more than once if they visit in multiple months.

For example:  12.123.456.78 visits in march and april, that's one Distinct IP counted in each month, but only 1 distinct IP if not grouping by month, you can't simply add the results of a grouped COUNT(DISTINCT ) to get the total COUNT(DISTINCT ) when not grouped.

This functionality can be helpful as it sheds some light on repeat visitors vs new.

Comment: Ah, of course! On further reading, this is apparently referred to as "the hotel problem".